# Are large radiators supposed to be colder?

Tags: radiator

I have a radiator in my room which is downstairs. It is a large radiators, almost 2 meters across.

It is 10 degrees colder than the other radiators in the house (mine is 37 others are 47, tested with an infrared thermometer).

I'm trying to make it hotter, any ideas? Are larger radiators colder?

*Extra information:*

- Radiator is colder at bottom than top (so I don't think it needs
  bleeding)
- The in and out valves are both turned up all the way
- It is downstairs so I wouldn't have thought it was the pressure?

Comment: check in the incoming water at the valve and see if the valve is open to the same point

Answer (score 1):

You don't think it needs bleeding - but have you tried? 99.9% of the time, that is the problem with water-type radiators and low heat delivery; lack of flow due to trapped air bubbles.

As a general rule, larger radiators do make more effective use of lower temperature water, but that does not seem to be your situation since you are evidently looking for more heat.

A noticeable stratification of the water temperature is not a good sign that things are circulating effectively, so I would draw the opposite conclusion that you have.

Comment: thanks! I've ordered a radiator key so hopefully that will fix it